# Testing a function from a module with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a module "test.js" which looks like this;

```
export default function main(){
   sub_main();
}

export function sub_main(){
 //Do something
}
```

I would like to test the method `sub_main` in Jasmine. I have tried to import sub_main() function to test in Jasmine using `import` statement but Jasmine complies "Unexpected token import" then I used the `require` statement. It now complies about `export` keyword in `test.js` module.

Answer (score 1):

This should help get you on the right path. You may want to look up some info on CommonJS modules as it looks like that is what you need to be using.

```
module.exports = {
    main: function() {
        this.sub_main();
    },

    sub_main: function() {
        return 'It Works!';
    }
}
```

And a working test example:

```
it('should work', function() {
  const sub_main = require('./path/to/myModule').sub_main;
  const itWorks = sub_main();

  expect(itWorks).toEqual('It Works!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're using is actually [ES6 imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), which is not supported by your node version.

You'd either either to use [Babel with Jasmine](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) before loading transpiled files into Jasmine, or write your code using the way that @tehbeardedone said on his answer, which is CommonJS.